# How to persists variables from Erlang program initialization for use in other functions?

Tags: erlang, global-variables

From what I've Googled, there are no global variables in Erlang?

Say I have function A (initialization code) which reads some info from a binary file into a few variables. I need to persist these variables for subsequent use in function B. Function B will be called many times whenever required.

What's the recommended practice for doing this?

Comment: Will B be called by one process or by many? If by one, is it the same process which calls A?

Comment: I suppose B could be called by many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ih you are looping function B and there is no change of configuration, you could just pass the configuration arguments to function B.

If configuration could be changed or it is too much overhead, I usually store the configuration paramets in an [ets](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) table.
This is what I have also observed by other developers.
You can also check this short ets introduction by [learnyousomeerlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/ets).

```
function_B(Arg1, ConfigVars) ->
    % do some stuff and modify Arg1
    function_B(Arg1_Modified, ConfigVars).
```

Comment: I think ets sounds like what I'm looking for.